# This query is not running for one day but not looping for another day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime;
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime;
DECLARE @CurrentDate DateTime;
DECLARE @Status INT;

Set @StartDate = '2016-08-19 00:00:00.000';
Set @EndDate = '2016-08-20 00:00:00.000'
Set @CurrentDate = @StartDate

While (@CurrentDate <= @EndDate)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[IntegrationLog]
    SET [CUSTOMER] = @CurrentDate, [PRODUCT] = @CurrentDate,
        [ORDER] = @CurrentDate, [ORDERLINE] = @CurrentDate,
        [DELIVERYNOTE] = @CurrentDate, [DELIVERYNOTEITEM] = @CurrentDate,
        [INVOICE] = @CurrentDate, [INVOICEITEM] = @CurrentDate,
        [WAREHOUSE] = @CurrentDate, [DELIVERYRETURN] = @CurrentDate

    declare @output_execution_id bigint
    exec dbo.Execute_ssis_Package @output_execution_id output

    Set @Status = (SELECT [STATUS] FROM [SSISDB].[internal].[operations]
                   WHERE operation_id = @output_execution_id) 

    While (@Status != 7)
    Begin

        WAITFOR DELAY  '00:00:59';
        CONTINUE;
        IF (@STATUS = 4)
        Break; 
    END
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate);
End
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: This query is executing for 1st start date and not updating to next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime;
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime;
DECLARE @CurrentDate DateTime;
DECLARE @Status INT;

Set @StartDate = '2016-08-19 00:00:00.000';
Set @EndDate = '2016-08-20 00:00:00.000'
Set @CurrentDate = @StartDate

While (@CurrentDate <= @EndDate)
BEGIN
   UPDATE [dbo].[IntegrationLog] SET [CUSTOMER] = @CurrentDate,[PRODUCT] = @CurrentDate,[ORDER] = @CurrentDate,[ORDERLINE] = @CurrentDate,
   [DELIVERYNOTE] = @CurrentDate,[DELIVERYNOTEITEM] = @CurrentDate,[INVOICE] = @CurrentDate,[INVOICEITEM] = @CurrentDate,
   [WAREHOUSE] = @CurrentDate, [DELIVERYRETURN] = @CurrentDate

   declare @output_execution_id bigint
   exec dbo.Execute_ssis_Package @output_execution_id output

   Set @Status = (SELECT [STATUS] FROM [SSISDB].[internal].[operations] WHERE operation_id = @output_execution_id) 

   While (@Status != 7)  -
   Begin

   WAITFOR DELAY  '00:00:59';
   CONTINUE;
   IF (@STATUS = 4)
   Break; 
   END
SET @CurrentDate =@CurrentDate+1;
End
```

Comment: The Problem You face is While Status !=7 Here what happen is if you are not getting the status =7 it's keep on running for 1st day itself Try to Change your queary Here While (@Status != 7)  -
   Begin

   WAITFOR DELAY  '00:00:59';
   CONTINUE;